# I need help consolidating a list of supplier names that change periodically?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that I am using as a questionnaire.

One of the questions is `Who are your wheel suppliers (mark all that apply)?` and there are 6 check boxes in column C to select 5 different wheel suppliers and an `Other` option. I have these check boxes linked to return whatever suppliers name is selected in the cell adjacent to the cell the check box is in in column I.

So depending on what wheel suppliers the customer selects there could be anywhere from 1-6 different suppliers selected. So once the customer has selected the wheel suppliers whatever suppliers are selected will show up in the correct cell in range `I45:50`.

What I am having a problem with is that I need these to pull into a data tab into one cell. I am having a problem coming up with a formula to put all the suppliers together as a list in one cell with commas separating each. Remember, it could be 1 supplier, could be 3, could be 6.

Any advice is much appreciated. I have tried using If formulas and Concatenate but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work like I want it to.

```
=CONCATENATE(Questionnaire!I45," ",Questionnaire!I46," ",Questionnaire!I47," ",Questionnaire!I48," ",Questionnaire!I49," ",Questionnaire!I50)
```

That is the best I've come up with but the problem with it is if the first supplier isn't selected then it will enter that space anyways and if the first supplier and the last supplier are selected it will have all those spaces in between.

Comment: Why dont you, in the end, remove all spaces? Substitute(string;" ";"")

Comment: Well, that's the only way I know how to do it. What is that you posted at the end of your comment?

Comment: You mean this (formula to remove all spaces) : SUBSTITUTE(string;" ";"")

Comment: Are helper cells amenable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method, this one using helper cells.

Say you have the data in `A1:A6`. In `B1`, input this formula: `=IF(LEN(A1)>0,A1&",","")`. Drag down to `B5`.

In `B6`, slight variation: `=IF(LEN(A6)>0,A6,",""")`.

In `C1`: `=CONCATENATE(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6)`.

What happens is the cells in the B column checks if their respective values in the A column are not blanks. If not, they will append `,` to it. Otherwise, they will return blanks (*not spaces*). The only variation is `B6`--since it's the end of the list, there's no `,` appended to it.

It's only a matter of concatenating them at this point. Removing any of the values in `A`, maybe by unchecking their checkbox, will reflect the change in `C1` properly.

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

**EDIT:**

To accommodate your formula, change your `CONCATENATE` formula to something like below:

`=LEFT(CONCATENATE(...),LEN(CONCATENATE(...)-1)`

What is does is it removes the rightmost character by getting, from the left, all the characters up until ***one less than the length of the result***. Obviously, fill in the `...` with the ranges you want to concatenate.

Let us know if this is what you need.

**FURTHER EDIT:**

```
=LEFT(CONCATENATE(Questionnaire!F45,Questionnaire!F46,Questionnaire!F47,Questionnaire‌​!F48,Questionnaire!F49,Questionnaire!F50),LEN(CONCATENATE(Questionnaire!F45,Questionnaire!F46,Questionnaire!F47,Questionnaire‌​!F48,Questionnaire!F49,Questionnaire!F50))-1)
```

Looks ugly, right? But does the job. Better if you use a named range, though, like below:

[image]

Now it's much shorter. Error on my end is because I don't have `Questionnaire` sheet, obviously.

Comment: Ok, I used your formula and it gave me an idea to alter mine to where it is working but still with one problem. I have the check boxes linked to column D. This is my formula: =IF(D45=TRUE,"KME, ",""). KME being one of the suppliers. So this enters each supplier with a comma after it. The only problem is if I only have one supplier it still puts the comma and it always has a comma after the last supplier name selected. Not sure how to get around that.

Comment: Ok, this is my formula, =CONCATENATE(Questionnaire!F45,Questionnaire!F46,Questionnaire!F47,Questionnaire!F48,Questionnaire!F49,Questionnaire!F50). How would I put that into the formula you mentioned? I tried but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Hmm, it's still not working correctly. Doesn't get rid of the last comma, just looks the same as my formula before.

Comment: Kindly post a screenshot. I honestly find it hard to believe it's not working. Either your data is wrong, or we're approaching this the totally wrong way. :)

Comment: Never mind, I apologize. I just had to make it a -2 instead of a -1 because I have it to where I put a space after the comma. I really appreciate all your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If J44 is blank and you are prepared to add something like `=IF(ISBLANK(I45),J44,J44&I45&", ")` in J45 (copied down) then perhaps:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(wheelC,LEN(wheelC)-2),0,"")
```

might suit, where wheelC is a named range of workbook scope for Questionnaire!J50.